# .Validate jQuery Validation Plugin not Ignoring Hidden Fields

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, jquery-validate

I'm new to jQuery and the .Validate jQuery Validation Plugin. I'm trying to integrate it into a multi-step form. Basically, I've set up a switch based on which next button the user presses and want to validate only that specific part of the form based on that.

When I successfully validate the first part of the form and move onto the second fieldset, the next set of fields come up already throwing validation errors. I've tried disabling the fields (which prevents the slider logic I'm using from working for some reason), specifically telling it to ignore that fieldset by class and directly declaring ignore: ":hidden" even though it's the default behavior.

I've placed the code I'm having trouble with in a jsFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/13x7Lbk7/4/ (updated)

Here is the specific part of my code that calls validation for the first step of the form:

```
$(".next").click(function(){

// Initialize form
    var form = $("#frmSignup");

    // Determine which step of the form we're on
    switch($(this).attr("value")) {

            case "step1": 

            $("#frmSignup").validate({
              rules: {
                    txtZipCode: {
                        required: true,
                        number: true,
                        minlength: 5,
                        maxlength: 5,
                    },
                    txtSchoolName: {
                        required: true,
                        minlength: 5,
                    },
                },
                messages: {
                    txtZipCode: {
                        required: "Zip Code Required",
                        number: "Enter a valid 5 digit zip code",
                        minlength: "Enter a valid 5 digit zip code",
                    },
                    txtSchoolName: {
                        required: "School Name Required",
                    },
                },            
            });

            break;
// --- SNIP ---

} // End step switch


    if ($("#frmSignup").valid() == true){

// Fieldset logic is here, see jsFiddle if you're curious

} // End isValid if

}); // End click function
```

And here is the relevant HTML for the first two fieldsets:

```
    <fieldset class="fsStep1">
    <h2>Step 1</h2>
    <h3>Information</h3>
    <label for="txtZipCode">Zip Code</label>
    <input type="text" name="txtZipCode" value="" pattern="\d*" id="txtZipCode" required />
    <label for="txtExample">Example Field</label>
    <input type="text" name="txtExample" value="" id="txtExample" required />
    <hr />
    <button name="next" value="step1" class="next action-button">Next</button>
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset class="fsStep2">
    <h2>Step 2</h2>
    <h3>Example</h3>
    <label for="txtInfo">Info</label>
    <input type="text" name="txtInfo" id="txtInfo" value="" pattern="[a-zA-Z -]+" required />
    <label for="txtOther">Other</label>
    <input type="text" name="txtOther" id="txtOther" value="" pattern="[a-zA-Z -]+" required />
    <hr />
    <input type="button" name="previous" class="previous action-button" value="Previous" />
    <button name="next" value="step2" class="next action-button">Next</button>
  </fieldset>
```

I'm sure I'm missing something boneheaded here, but I keep going through the code, reviewing documentation, searching the web and I've been coming up against a blank wall all day. Please put me out of my mysery and tell me exactly why I'm stupid. :) Thank you!

Comment: I thought you only had an issue where hidden fields are not ignored.  However, your jsFiddle is completely broken.... there is no validation at all.  Please check the error console and fix the syntax errors.

Comment: That is the issue I'm having. I just made a mistake copying over the javascript from my live document to the jsFiddle. Very sorry about that. I added the novalidate tag you suggested and the behavior so far is the same. I'll keep looking at it.

Comment: **I did not make that suggestion**.  The jQuery Validate plugin already dynamically adds the `novalidate` attribute automatically.

Comment: I also think it would be a very good idea to further simplify the jsFIddle to only show the minimal amount of code that causes the issue.

Comment: You're right. I'm new at this and making a fool of myself. I removed all but 2 steps now, and took out all the javascript I could: http://jsfiddle.net/13x7Lbk7/4/

Comment: FYI:  `if ($("#frmSignup").valid() ...` will trigger validation.  You cannot call the `.valid()` test without triggering the validation.  Not sure if that's your root problem, but it's something for you to look at.

Comment: Also, it's really not clear why you've put `.validate()` method inside of a `switch`.   Again FYI, that's only the method for ***initializing*** the plugin... you call it once on DOM ready; should not be called multiple times based on a set of conditions.

Comment: Okay, that makes sense. I'll ditch the switch and clean up my concepts. There must be a better example out there I missed to work from. I think my whole concept here is flawed.

Comment: Please search under my username and the jQuery Validate tag for stepped forms.  There are a couple different ways.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, if it does not like hidden fields, use this trick to *hide them*:

```
/*Hide all except first fieldset*/
#frmSignup fieldset:not(.shown) {
    height:0;
    overflow:hidden;
    position: absolute;
    top: -9999px;
}
```

Add the `.shown` class to your first fieldset.

You have no `.next` elements, but `button`s named `next`.

So replace `$(".next").click` with `$("button[name='next']").click`.

Instead of `if ($("#frmSignup").valid() == true)`, you can do `if ($("#frmSignup").valid())`.

And you'll need to remove the `required` attributes in your HTML, as *hidden* elements are not filled yet, so they prevent you from going to the next step. Let `$.validate()` do the job.

#### JS Fiddle Demo

Comment: The jQuery Validate plugin will reliably ignore hidden fields.  There is more likely something within the OP's code that is triggering the validation when the panel is revealed.

Comment: Thank you so, so much, blex. You're a star.

Comment: And thank you too, Sparky. You're totally right about me approaching this the wrong way. I'm dropping the switch and redoing this now. I'm going to edit in a new, fixed jsFiddle when I'm done in case anyone googles for this and needs it.